# EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: entity-framework, ninject

I'm having a problem connecting to my database using Entity Framework. I'm randomly getting the following error when attempting to connect to the database...

```
EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
```

To give you some background on my setup, I'm using MVC 4 and Ninject. I'm also using the Repository and Unit of Work pattern described in [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). I'm using the default NinjectWebCommon file in MVC 4 and my RegisterServices method is as follows...

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IMyEntities>().To<MyEntities>();
    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
    // UnitOfWork has a dependency on MyEntities

    kernel.Bind<IAccountManager>().To<AccountManager>(); 
    kernel.Bind<ITransactionManager>().To<TransactionManager>(); 
    // AccountManager and TransactionManager has a dependency on UnitOfWork
}
```

My page loads fine but I have 2 ajax calls on the page that cause the error. When the ajax calls are removed, the error never occurs. When there's only 1 of the ajax calls made, the error never occurs. It's only when both calls are made simultaneously that the error occurs.

Here are the 2 different web api controllers...

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IAccountManager _AccountManager;

    public AccountController(IAccountManager accountManager)
    {
        _AccountManager = accountManager;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        IEnumerable<Account> accounts = _AccountManager.Get();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, accounts);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TransactionController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ITransactionManager _TransactionManager;

    public TransactionController(ITransactionManager transactionManager)
    {
        _TransactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        IEnumerable<Transaction> transactions = _TransactionManager.Get();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, transactions);
    }
}
```

I really don't know what to do here. I've read every article relating to this on StackOverflow and Google but I can't find an answer. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to stop this issue from happening?

Comment: It's not entirely clear where the underlying context's are situated and what there life cycle is, but you have to make sure that both controllers have contexts of their own. Now it seems that one controller addresses the context and the other controller does the same while the first one is still busy.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, not using transactions (TransactionScope class) seems to have temporarily solved my problem. I have yet to figure out what the TransactionScope exactly does to ruin the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, eventually I found out that the same UnitOfWork instance was being accessed from different thread. I'm not very familiar with Ninject, but I suggest checking your Account and TransactionManager to make sure they are accessing different instances of UnitOfWork.

Comment: This sounds like what is happening to me. When you found that the same UnitOfWork was being accessed from a different thread, what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: I was using Unity Container for DI purposes and had mistakenly given a set instance to the resolver for Repositories. So each I resolved a Repository it had the same constant UnitOfWork, and in my case also the same ObjectContext. In the end I just moved the creation of the UnitOfWork instances to my Repository class and I haven't had a problem since.